# Remove underlining on search bar with speech-to-text

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

When I search on my search bar manually (typing the words), the text is completely fine.

However, when I use the speech-to-text button just to the left of the space bar on my iPhone, I get a blue dotted line underneath my text.

I am not sure the reason for this, but how can I remove this?

[image]

**If you have any questions, please ask**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When iOS is not sure about what is dictated, it adds a hyperlink with best suggestions if any. I am not sure if there is a way to remove it or if it is a good idea to remove it.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will just leave it how it is then.